# SQL Server 2017 Performance - querying parameters

Tags: sql-server, parameters, cpu

I've got SQL Server Express 2017 (RTM) 14.0.1000.169 installed on a low-powered W2019 server on AWS. It has 2GB of RAM and 2.40GHz processor. (t2.small).

I've had the same setup on other AWS machines with less power than this and they don't seem to have this problem. But those machines would have SQL Server 2014 and windows 2008R2.

The problem is that when I run specific queries, they are taking huge amounts of time. In my applications, I have a routine that sniffs parameters for the stored procedure being called so that the .NET can provide parameters as needed without me having to code every single procedure separately.

To do this, I have been running

```
[sys].[sp_procedure_params_100_managed] @procedure_name=@PRC
```

but this routine in this new machine is taking up to 30 seconds to run.

So I've manually created something simpler to see if I can view any issues with the execution plan, but it still runs extremely slowly:

```
select o.name, prm.*
from sys.parameters prm
inner join sys.objects o on prm.object_id=o.object_id
where o.type='P'
    and o.name='prc_THEPROCNAME'
```

To be clear, there are only 30 stored procedures in the whole database. But the query above takes 2860ms to run in SSMS and is showing 1285 reads.

When I run that on my little win10 machine with SQL Server Express 2014, it takes 12ms with 568 reads on a similar (but larger) database.

So my question is this: what is the issue with this environment? Is a t2.small too underpowered for Win2019? Does SQL Server 2017 have that much more overhead than SQL Server 2014? Or is it possible that I have a bad configuration somewhere in my SQL Server setup?

Comment: Are there other applications running that might be competing with SQL Server for resources?

Comment: If SQL Server had any performance issues hundreds of thousands of developers would have noticed years ago. It could be that the database schema is causing issues, or it could be that there are too many other clients on that AWS server.

Comment: In any case, if you want to check the load use `Activity Monitor`, Extended Events, SSMS reports or  the server/database dashboards on Azure Data Studio. Running a timing a stored procedure will tell you nothing except "it's slow". The appropriate tools will tell you how much CPU is used, if there are any lock issues, slow IO etc

Comment: The only things that are running are Terminal Services and an ASP.net back-end. The database schema should be clean; it's a brand new install with just this one database on it and it has next to no tables.

Comment: The useful information is `it has next to no tables`. Again, the problem probably has nothing to do with SQL Server, and the *VM* runs on a busy host, which you can do nothing about. Use Task Manager or Resource Monitor to see what's going on, although I suspect simply opening those will be slow. It may have slow IO, which would appear as high Kernel usage in Task Manager or long disk queues in Resource Monitory. Check the available memory, how much is in use?

Comment: AWS doesn't offer any performance guarantees for VMs. Even large instances can suffer from the "noisy neighbour" problem, ie other VMs on the same host taking too many resources. A *small* instance though has no performance guarantees at all.

Answer (score 0):

I am using SQL Server on a very similar AWS platform (t2.small) and have no performance issues with your query (< 1s). You haven't mentioned whether any other queries are suffering performance problems, but that would be helpful. My answer then would be that the t2.small is not underpowered and it is highly unlikely that SQL '17 would have greater difficulty than SQL '14 when executing this query.